# Неотлавливаемое Исключение android

Tags: android, java

имеется прога. На моем устройстве с андроидом 4,4 работает хорошо. Запустив у друга на андроиде 4,0 при вызове кое-какой функции вылетело исключение прямо в среду выполнения. Прога естественно закрылась, даже не указав примерную причину. Запустив прогу на эмуляторе 4,0 с настройками максимум соответствующими устройству друга, я ошибку повторить не смог(всё работает хорошо). Подключить устройство к ADT нет возможности. Как мне узнать что за баг вылазит ? Знаю про статический метод у Thread. Но Есть ли такой способ который бы непосредстввенно в окне ошибки указал хоть какие подробности?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Установите ему [CatLog - Logcat Reader!](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat&hl=ru) или [aLogcat (free) - logcat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat). В результате у Вас будет доступ к logcat. Сохраняете лог и исследуете.

Comment: а как быть если программа будет у посторонних людей? которые могут и 1 балл на маркете поставить :)

Comment: есть много сервисов, которые Вам помогут. К примеру, самый простой [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra). Он собирает отчет о падениях и отправляет в googledocs. Потом можно открыть и почитать. Выпустить обновление. Статья на хабре - [Как получить наибольшую выгоду от Crash Reports или упрощаем себе жизнь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/123542/).


Подобных сервисов куча. Тот же [Flurry](www.flurry.com) ещё и статистику выдаст.

Comment: спасибо за ACRA. очень понравилась .